# Add right mark image on right corner of button after click in Android

Tags: android, button

I have a button on screen with some background image on it, I want when I click on that button, another image from the drawable , i,e, right mark.png , placed at right corner of the button.

How I achieve this task.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: any graphical explanation would help.

Comment: I just want to set image at run time when I click on button programatically

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
int tick= R.drawable.tick_mark;
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, tick, 0);//put this in your onclick listener
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following step by step:

1. Create a button with background image and put it in a relative layout.
2. To the right of the button, set the rightmark.png in the xml file.
3. In the java code, on create method, make the rightmark.png's visibility as "GONE" (Hidden)
4. On the button's on click listener, do your action and when required, set the rightmark.png's visibility as VISIBLE.

Let me know if you need code samples for this approach.

**EDIT:**
The XML File would be somewhat like this. `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"` should be used for aligning the image to right of the button.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="100" >
```

```
  <!-- Your RelativeLayout Items -->
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:text="Button" />

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
      android:src="@drawable/rightmark" />

  </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have do this, but rightmark.png placed at top left of the screen.

Comment: It must be a relative layout.. Please Wait.. I will post the code in my answer.

Comment: @UserNew: Code for XML Included. Please check if it helps. Let me know if it doesn't.